# Anyway to know it is stored in savedsearch or not

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'd like to search using savedsearch.

Here my code snippet goes.

```
 var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('item', search_id, null, null);
```

`search_id` is defined as parameter in text field.
This is `suitelet` script so if you couldn't find similar `search_id` in `savedsearch` then it throws exception.

To avoid this I'd like to check if there is any similar internal id in saved searches.

For instance if there are two saved searches which ids are `customsearch1`, `customsearch2`.

If `search_id` is `'cust'` then it throws exception and script finished with error.

It shows this in script log

```
'That search or mass update does not exist.'
```

Looking forward to hearing from you soon.
Regard

Answer (score 1):

You can do a saved search of saved searches. You could take the results and use regex to determine if there is a similiar one. Use trim plus regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent this by changing your search_id parameter to a List/Record of Saved Searches.

Any reason why it has to be a text field?