# nlapiSearchRecord Sending an Error Instead of Just null

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have created a search using nlapiSearchRecord(). When I tried to implement it, instead of just returning null when there are no results I receive the error 
`That search or mass update does not exist.` It worked fine on a different account but I can't figure out what is causing the problem now.

The code should search if a record that matches rec_val exists. If it doesn't match then continue the loop. But instead of continuing the loop an error is thrown. I have tried using the info from a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213632/anyway-to-know-it-is-stored-in-savedsearch-or-not) but to no avail. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var rec_val = 'some value';
  var column = new nlobjSearchColumn('custfield15');
  var filter = new nlobjSearchFilter('custfield15', null, 'is', rec_val);
  var search = nlapiSearchRecord('inventoryitem', null, filter, column);

  if (search) {
    var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('inventoryitem', search[0].getId());                  
    rec.setFieldValue('custitem5', rec_val);
    nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
    continue;
  }else{  
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Notice:', 'Nothing to Update'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: @W3BGUY I only got this `INVALID_SEARCH That search or mass update does not exist.`

Comment: The code is fine. Must be something else.

Comment: I just tried again and it just worked. None of my code changed. I guess you're right it must be something else. Weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with my code. It just suddenly started working which means it was probably something else that was causing the error.

Comment: NetSuite has been experiencing a LOT of issues lately (performance, uptime, native code changes, permissions changes, etc...).  I would not be surprised if it was related to one of those issues.